# Why does "bash 2>out.txt" hide bash output?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm currently using zsh, and I'm trying to start `bash` from zsh so that all commands ran in this `bash` would have their stderr redirected to `out.txt`.

`bash 2>out.txt` surely did the job, but normal bash output (`stdout`?) disappeared.

What I expect:

```
zsh> bash 2>out.txt
user@pc:~$ pwd
/home/user
```

What I got:

```
pwd
/home/user
```

The `user@pc:~$` thing has disappeared.

Why is this happening? I thought `user@pc:~$` was supposed to be printed to `stdout`, but I tried redirecting `stdout` to `/dev/null` and it was still showing. It was also not showing in `out.txt` either, which means it isn't printed to `stderr`? Then why does `2>out.txt` make it disappear?

Comment: The text file is probably going to be flushed when you close the session or write enough to flush a block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash only prints the prompt in interactive mode; redirecting its stderr to a non-terminal takes it out of that mode. You can force interactive mode with `-i`, and if you do you'll notice that the prompt is in fact printed to stderr, not stdout.

But in general, if you want to capture an interactive session, you should use the `script` program (e.g. `script -c bash out.txt` on Linux, `script out.txt bash` on BSD/macOS).

Comment: I checked and script out.txt bash actually starts another zsh? (I'm on ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the behavior I expect in any matter? Because `script` seems to capture everything, which is not what I want to achieve

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get bash to print its prompt to somewhere other than stderr. You'd have to individually redirect the stderr of each command you type if you want to still get the prompt.